# Crontab - First Wednesday of the month that is followed by the first Monday of that month

Tags: linux, cron

Looking to execute a script on the first Monday of the month, then a different script on the first Wednesday of the month.

The issue is that if a new month starts on a Tuesday, for example, then the "first Wednesday of the month" action will hit first.  I'd like to have this configured so that the "first Wednesday of the month" action only occurs if it follows a Monday within that month.

Logic can be used to figure this out from a scripting perspective, but the problem is that I need this in a cron expression since that is the only way I can schedule this in the system I am using (it requires a cron expression for advanced scheduling, and details of this system is not relevant to this question).

Edit: There is no dependency or relationship between the aforementioned scripts being executed by cron.  For the sake of simplicity for the question, they would simply be two separate cronjobs in the same crontab.

Comment: If you want just the first Wednesday after a Monday, let's say at 15:00, you can do so:

`0       15       3-9               *                3              /path/to/command`

It will run on Wednesdays, provided that the day of the month is between 3 (the first possible day for a Wednesday after a Monday) and 9 (the last possible day, when the month starts on Tuesday).

Comment: I marked the question as a duplicate because cron is a very basic scheduler and it does not provide native support for job dependencies, it can not guarantee that your Wednesday script will run only when the job on the first Monday of the month has completed successfully. That requires more thorough checking

Comment: @HBruijn Thanks for the explanation, however clearly this should not be marked as a duplicate since a) the duplicate Q&A does not address the question at all and b) I am already receiving possible answers (see Eduardo's comment) and upvotes.  Please revert this duplicate edit.  I'm disappointed that there isn't some kind of check to prevent hasty duplicate marks.  Furthermore, there is no "job dependency" as you mentioned.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I think that is the answer I was looking for; I'll need to test this out.  Can you provide this as an answer?

Comment: @HBruijn I don't think this is a duplicate. I provided the answer to this very specific question, but could do so only in the comments. Could you "unduplicate" it so that I can provide it as an actual answer?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani you should click on the "reopen" option next to the "edit" option below my question in order to vote for a reopen

Comment: I guess I don't have enough reputation for that. No "reopen" option. It seems only @HBruijn or somebody with enough reputation can undo the duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run a command on the first Monday of a month, I would suggest this `crontab` line, initially:

```
# m h d o w u cmd
0 3 1-7 * 1 root /usr/local/sbin/kachow
```

Because the week day of the 8th month day is definitely the same as of the 1st month day, a `crontab` line specifying both the first seven days of the month and Monday is expected to achieve initial intention, isn't it?

Unfortunately, that `crontab` line is wrong. Actually, the `kachow` script would then run everyday on the first seven days of each month and also on every Monday. `crontab` uses an `OR` logic to combine days of month and days of week. The [`crontab (5)` manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) provides the following note:

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields - day of month, and day of week. If both fields are restricted (ie, aren't *), the command will be run when *either* field matches the current time. For example, "30 4 1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.

---

The logic needs to be defined in the command part of the `crontab` line too in order to restrict command execution to the first Monday of the month. Therefore, either one of the following lines will work as expected:

```
# m h d o w u cmd
0 3 1-7 * * root [ $(date +%u) -eq 1 ] && /usr/local/sbin/kachow
```

```
# m h d o w u cmd
0 3 * * 1 root [ $(date +%-d) -le 7 ] && /usr/local/sbin/kachow
```

Similarly, a script expected to run on the first Wednesday of a month only if following a Monday within the same month may be scheduled by one of the `crontab` lines below. I believe the 8th and 9th days of the month should be excluded from the logic; on the contrary case, `woof-woof` script would run unexpectedly on the second Wednesday of the month.

```
# m h d o w u cmd
0 3 3-7 * * root [ $(date +%u) -eq 3 ] && /usr/local/sbin/woof-woof
```

```
# m h d o w u cmd
0 3 * * 3 root [ $(date +%-d) -ge 3 -a $(date +%-d) -le 7 ] && /usr/local/sbin/woof-woof
```

Comment: Also there is a hack to switch cron logic to test for both day restrictions simultaneously https://superuser.com/a/1743912/318005 .